# I am missing 1/2 in this integral

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve a integral for cal 2

using substitution.

> $$\int x(6+x^2)^{10} dx , u = 6 + x^2$$

I know the answer is

> $$\frac{(6+x^2)^{11}}{22}+C$$

i can't figure out where the last $\frac{1}{2}$ came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it help to work the problem in reverse?  Let $y=\dfrac{(6+x^2)^{11}}{22}$.  Now we make the substitution $u=6+x^2$ and apply the chain rule.

$$y=\dfrac{u^{11}}{22},\frac{dy}{du}=\dfrac{u^{10}}2=\dfrac{(6+x^2)^{10}}2$$
$$u=6+x^2,\frac{du}{dx}=2x$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{2x(6+x^2)^{10}}2=x(6+x^2)^{10}$$

Now when integrating, the chain rule must still be considered.  We attempt to rewrite $\int f(x)dx$ as $\int g(u)du$.  If we wish to make the substitution

$$u=6+x^2,du=2xdx\text{, then }$$

$$\int x(6+x^2)^{10}dx=\int\frac12(6+x^2)^{10}(2xdx)=\frac12\int u^{10}du$$

To get from the first integral to the second integral, I just multiplied by $2$ and $\frac12$ (net result a multiplication by $1$) and rearranged terms to separate out $du$.  Then the constant was pulled outside the integral and the substitution applied.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that your differential changes from $dx$ to $du$. If $u = x^2+6$, then $du = \frac{du}{dx}dx = 2xdx$ or $dx = \frac{du}{2x}$. Making this substitution gives the missing $\frac{1}{2}$.

To see how it all comes together, notice that

$$\int x(x^2+6)^{10} dx = \int xu^{10}\frac{du}{2x} = \frac{1}{2}\int u^{10}du.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Found the typo that you wrote $x^2 + 2$ instead of $x^2 + 6$

Comment: Thanks for that. I had $2$ on the brain because of the missing $\frac{1}{2}$ it seems.

Comment: how does the differential change i can account for the x because of the x out side of the parentheses but not that 2 if you take the derivative of u then you get 2x but that leaves the outer most x out in the cold.

Comment: @wolfcall I have edited my post. Is it clear now?

Comment: Been mulling it over and still can't quite wrap my head around it. Sorry. Take a look at my other comments in the other answer and see if that helps you figure out the link i am missing.

Comment: How did you treat the $x$ in your integral after substitution?

Answer (score 1):

Observe carefully that if $u = 6 + x^2$, then $du = 2x\,dx$.  The integral becomes

$$\begin{aligned}
\int x(6 + x^2)^{10}\,dx &= \int \dfrac{1}{2}(2x\,dx)u^{10}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2} \int u^{10}\,du\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{u^{11}}{11} + \mbox{C}\\
&= \dfrac{(x^2 + 6)^{11}}{22} + \mbox{C}
\end{aligned}$$

$\frac{1}{2}$ comes from the substitution.  First, determine the differentials of the substitution.  Then, make the substitution of $x\,dx$ with the constant (If $du = 2x\,dx$, take $x\,dx$ and rewrite it as $2x\,dx$.  Then, multiply that by $\frac{1}{2}$ and substitute $2x\,dx$ with $du$).

Another way of seeing this is: Solve for $x\,dx$ and make the substitution.  This is equivalent to the first approach.

Comment: by the differential of the substitution do you mean the derivative?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean by differential.  Differential is the change of "something" (e.g. change of function, change of variable).

Comment: so i have to make the outermost x = the derivative of the substitution?